# What's the use of .tmfs folder on SD card?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, file-system

What is the use of `.tmfs` folder on SD card?

ps. there is only a file in it with Chinese filename ...

Comment: It's using some space. Honestly: Couldn't you give some more details, e.g. what's inside, does it reside in the SDCard's root directory, etc? It seems that folder is not present on all devices (I've never seen it with mine), so it could even be specific to some app you use.

Comment: Oh, I guess it's created by QQSecure as there is a empty file with a Chinese filename in it.

Comment: A file with a chinese name most likely points to something app-specific. And makes the question quite localized, one could say :) So if your question has found an answer, you may decide: if you think it's useful for others, please post it as answer (with some more details). If you feel it's rather trivial and of no larger interest, I'd say you'd better delete the question then before someone else closes it as "too localized" :)